# Firebase: Custom claims require my users to log out and log in before taking effect?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

When assigned a custom claim, my users in the client have to log out and log in before the claims show on their account. I spent all today trying to figure out why my claims were not setting and it turns out the user has to relog in order for the claim to show LOL rip 5 hours of my day for no reason. Is there anything I can add to make it refresh the users info without them having to relog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom claims may be force refreshed by calling `currentUser.getIdToken(true)`.

From the docs...

> ## Propagate custom claims to the client
>
> After new claims are modified on a user via the Admin SDK, they are propagated to an authenticated user on the client side via the ID token in the following ways:
>
> - A user signs in or re-authenticates after the custom claims are modified. The ID token issued as a result will contain the latest claims.
> - An existing user session gets its ID token refreshed after an older token expires.
> - An ID token is force refreshed by calling `currentUser.getIdToken(true)`.

Comment: worked perfect thanks